# Chars sanitization and XSS

Tags: javascript, xss

I was doing the Google's XSS game (https://xss-game.appspot.com/level4) and I managed to solve the 4th level. I didn't completely undestand how, though.
I don't understand why if I inject the encoding version of a char (let's say %3B) this is translated into the char itself (that is ';') inside the final HTML page. I mean who does this, the browser? Why?

Furthermore, I don't understand where in the code the the injected chars are checked. I made some tests and I've seen that if I try to inject strings like `'()';"'` whatever comes after the `;` is cut out! Where does this happen in the code?

Finally, if I inject a tag like `<asd>` it is encoded within the `<div>`  (that is `&lt;asd&gt;`) but it does not in the onload attribute of the `<img>` tag, where in the code this stuff is performed?

Comment: For anyone interested in answering, to pass level 1: search for `<script>alert();</script>`; to pass level 2: comment `<b onclick="alert()">comment</b>` and click on it; to pass level 3: enter the following URL in the game browser `https://xss-game.appspot.com/level3/frame#'><script>alert();</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer makes a number of assumptions because I don't have access to Google's client side or server side code (the link goes to an error page because I haven't played the game to reach the level)).

The ((probably) server side) URL parser (which will be part of the server side code) is responsible for converting percent-encoded data in URLs into characters.

`;` is a key/value separator in form encoding syntax. The URL parser will cut off data at that point.

Responsibility for converting text into HTML is usually given to the template engine, but might be done in some general server side code before data gets to the template (assuming there is a template, the general server side code might just smash strings together).

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage level 4 just enter 
        `')*alert('xss`